# Divide ArrayList into equal halves depending on number of threads

Tags: multithreading

I have an ArrayList contains 10 objects (rows) as predefined. I am getting user input "Number of threads" from keyboard. After that, list has to be divided based on number of threads. (list/no of threads)

After splitting ArrayList, i need to create instances of "number of threads" and pass the list corresponding to each thread & start the threads.

```
int numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        int size = shipmentList.size();
        int listequal = size/numberOfThreads;
        for (int i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++)
        {
             t1 = new ExportShipmentThread();
             t1.setShipmentList(shipmentList.subList(0, listequal));
            t1.start();
            t1.join();
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code ?

Comment: What do you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I was able to print only the first 5 rows from the List. I know, I'm iterating only first set but not sure how to write the for loop to process the data. I need to print all 10 rows in the list.